# How do I show $T:V \rightarrow W$ there are bases $B$ of $V$ and $B'$ of $W$ such that $A_{T,B,B'} \in S$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ and $W$ be the real vector spaces, and let $T: V \rightarrow W$ be a linear map. If the dimension of $V$ and $W$ are 3 and 5, respectively, then for any bases $B$ of $V$ and $B'$ of $W$, we can represent $T$ by a $5 \times 3$ matrix $A_{T,B,B'}$.

Find a set $S$ of $5 \times 3 $ matrices as small as possible such that for any $T:V \rightarrow W$ there are bases $B$ of $V$ and $B'$ of $W$ such that $A_{T,B,B'} \in S$.

Can anyone suggest some direction, how do I find the set $S$?

Comment: **Hint:** $|S|=4$ according to the possible ranks $0,1,2,3$ of linear maps.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Gaussian elimination. Any operation you perform on rows and columns is allowed since you can change the basis on $V$ and on $W$. The question then becomes, if you can do operations on both rows and columns, what are the possible end results.

Second hint: Rank is relevant here.

Hope that helps,